# InvalidCharacterError in IEwith angularJS

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

```
InvalidCharacterError <div class="ng-scope" ng-view="">
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: {
         [functions]: ,
         __proto__: { },
         ABORT_ERR: 20,
         code: <Permission denied>,
         constructor: {
            [functions]: ,
            __proto__: { },
            ABORT_ERR: 20,
            DATA_CLONE_ERR: 25,
            DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2,
            HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: 3,
            INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1,
            INUSE_ATTRIBUTE_ERR: 10,
            INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: 15,
            INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: 5,
            INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR: 13,
            INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR: 24,
            INVALID_STATE_ERR: 11,
            NAMESPACE_ERR: 14,
            NETWORK_ERR: 19,
            NO_DATA_ALLOWED_ERR: 6,
            NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: 7,
            NOT_FOUND_ERR: 8,
            NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: 9,
            PARSE_ERR: 81,
            prototype: {
               [functions]: ,
               __proto__: { },
               ABORT_ERR: 20,
               code: <Permission denied>,
               constructor: { },
               DATA_CLONE_ERR: 25,
               DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2,
               HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: 3,
               INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1,
               INUSE_ATTRIBUTE_ERR: 10,
               INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: 15,
               INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: 5,
               INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR: 13,
               INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR: 24,
               INVALID_STATE_ERR: 11,
               message: <Permission denied>,
               name: <Permission denied>,
               NAMESPACE_ERR: 14,
               NETWORK_ERR: 19,
               NO_DATA_ALLOWED_ERR: 6,
               NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: 7,
               NOT_FOUND_ERR: 8,
               NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: 9,
               PARSE_ERR: 81,
               QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: 22,
               SECURITY_ERR: 18,
               SERIALIZE_ERR: 82,
               SYNTAX_ERR: 12,
               TIMEOUT_ERR: 23,
               TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: 17,
               URL_MISMATCH_ERR: 21,
               VALIDATION_ERR: 16,
               WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: 4
            },
            QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: 22,
            SECURITY_ERR: 18,
            SERIALIZE_ERR: 82,
            SYNTAX_ERR: 12,
            TIMEOUT_ERR: 23,
            TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: 17,
            URL_MISMATCH_ERR: 21,
            VALIDATION_ERR: 16,
            WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: 4
         },
         DATA_CLONE_ERR: 25,
         DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2,
         HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: 3,
         INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1,
         INUSE_ATTRIBUTE_ERR: 10,
         INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: 15,
         INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: 5,
         INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR: 13,
         INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR: 24,
         INVALID_STATE_ERR: 11,
         message: <Permission denied>,
         name: <Permission denied>,
         NAMESPACE_ERR: 14,
         NETWORK_ERR: 19,
         NO_DATA_ALLOWED_ERR: 6,
         NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: 7,
         NOT_FOUND_ERR: 8,
         NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: 9,
         PARSE_ERR: 81,
         QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: 22,
         SECURITY_ERR: 18,
         SERIALIZE_ERR: 82,
         SYNTAX_ERR: 12,
         TIMEOUT_ERR: 23,
         TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: 17,
         URL_MISMATCH_ERR: 21,
         VALIDATION_ERR: 16,
         WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: 4
      },
      ABORT_ERR: 20,
      code: 5,
      constructor: { },
      DATA_CLONE_ERR: 25,
      DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2,
      HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: 3,
      INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1,
      INUSE_ATTRIBUTE_ERR: 10,
      INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: 15,
      INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: 5,
      INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR: 13,
      INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR: 24,
      INVALID_STATE_ERR: 11,
      message: "InvalidCharacterError",
      name: "InvalidCharacterError",
      NAMESPACE_ERR: 14,
      NETWORK_ERR: 19,
      NO_DATA_ALLOWED_ERR: 6,
      NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: 7,
      NOT_FOUND_ERR: 8,
      NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: 9,
      PARSE_ERR: 81,
      QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: 22,
      SECURITY_ERR: 18,
      SERIALIZE_ERR: 82,
      SYNTAX_ERR: 12,
      TIMEOUT_ERR: 23,
      TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: 17,
      URL_MISMATCH_ERR: 21,
      VALIDATION_ERR: 16,
      WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: 4
   }
   "<div class="ng-scope" ng-view="">"
```

This is the error stack i get when i run my application on IE(any version).
I have not idea what this means.

This is my index.html file:

```
    </head>
    <body id="quotesBase" >
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="head-hr b1">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row header">
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 cs-1"><a href="#0" class="aq-logo"></a></div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 cs-1"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 cs-1"><strong class="toll-free-num">1800-103-3999 <span>[24 x 7 Toll Free]</span></strong></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
```

The application runs fine in other browsers.
IS there any js that i have to load that helps run this application in IE

Comment: some hints - http://stackoverflow.com/q/15913308/ - and [google result](https://www.google.com/search?q=InvalidCharacterError+IE)

Comment: What view are you trying to load in? Can we also see it's markup. Can you put a repro online for us to access directly?